# Set the selected value of the ArrayList to the class varibale in the AlertBuilder

Tags: android

I am displaying the value of an ArrayList `[5,10,15]` in AlertBuilder window  after the user selected an item of the list I want to set the value of the item to the class variable `number` also `5 or 10 or 15`. I tried it with which but I am getting the arrayList position value. How can I get the displayed value in the dialog window to assign it to the class variable?

I appreciate any help.

```
  //class variable
  int number;

    ArrayList<Integer> routeList = extras
            .getIntegerArrayList("stop_route");
    int routeListSize = routeList.size();
    //if(routeListSize > 0 && route_number == 0)
    if(routeListSize > 0){


        String[] charSequence = new String[routeList.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i<routeList.size(); i++) {
            charSequence[i] = String.valueOf(routeList.get(i));
        }
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    builder.setTitle("Please help us to track the route, has this route arrived the stop? ");



    builder.setMultiChoiceItems(charSequence, null,
            new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {


                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which,
                        boolean isChecked) {

                    if(isChecked){

                    }

                }
            });

        builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                    }
                });

   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
builder.setMultiChoiceItems(charSequence, null,
        new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {


            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which,
                    boolean isChecked) {

                if(isChecked){
                    number = routeList.get(which);
                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: It works thanks bu do you know how can I set it only when the user clicks the ok button and not when he checks the item?

Comment: http://goo.gl/UUi2Af - There is nothing you can do for that it seems. When you click on an item, the onclick event occurs. You close the dialog box by clicking on the buttons

Comment: Why do you need it to occur at button click? why not at item selection?  Anyway, if you want to try something...instead of setting number, just create a class variable (`selectedItems`) of the same size as charSequence. Instead of `number = routeList.get(which)` do `selectedItems.set(which, true)`. In `setPositiveButton(...)`'s `onClick` do you magic instead

Comment: I think I dont need it anymore. Selecting item is doing well.